# Port forwarding through 2 routers with mixed IPv6 and IPv4

Tags: router, port-forwarding, modem, ipv6

My ISP recently changed to IPv6 which made my port forwarding through 2 routers not working anymore.

My internal router only supports IPv4 afaik. Is there a way to still forward ports through these 2 routers:
[image]

Comment: Checked with your ISP about port forwarding instructions?

Comment: Is DHCP on the second router turned off?  Be best for you to post the make/model of BOTH routers to get the best advice.

Answer (score 1):

Given new routers go for as little as $20, and the last new one I bought in that price range (B/G/N wifi plus four wire ports and separate uplink) supports IPv6, if you confirm your existing home router doesn't support the new standard, the best course might be to just buy a new one.